# How to move data to another folder in memsql

Tags: singlestore

Working with `memsql cluster` as primary storage design, by default data files are installed in a place like the following on CentOS 6.x:

```
/var/lib/memsql-ops/data/installs/MI9dfcc72a5b044f2694b5f7028803a21e
```

Is there any way to relocate the data path to another folder on the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a best way but it works. I just re-install MemSQL to other directory:

```
sudo mkdir /data/memsql
sudo ./install.sh --root-dir /data/memsql
```

In this case MemSQL Ops still will be in `/var/lib/memsql-ops` but all nodes will be installed to `/data/memsql` directory (look at symlink `/var/lib/memsql`) and all data will be inside this directory too.

P.S. Additional installation options you can find use `memsql-ops agent-install --help` command.